# USB-C to Low-Profile Connector Cable

Tags: pcb-design, usb, connector, usb-c, usb-pd

I'm designing a board that involves USB-C power delivery (PD) and I am in need of a very specialized connector. The project design does not allow for mounting a USB-C connector on the board itself due to height issues as well as the large "notch" around a cable not fitting within the housing of the board if the connector could be added. I have been researching many different options, but none are directly compatible with USB-C. It seems like an intermediary board would be necessary for this, but this is not an appealing option and would likely be turned down by my coworkers.

Does anybody know of a low-profile connector (< 4mm height) that can handle up to 15W USB PD and be interfaced to a 2.0 USB-C cable?

For reference, this is the closest cable that I have been able to find, but the FPC would not likely bend correctly for the housing and I do not need the 3.2 specifications. No high speed data is used.
https://neoconix.com/fpconnected-usb3-2-usb-3-2-fpc-jumper/

Comment: Mid mount USB-C receptacles exist. If you cut a slot on PCB and mount one, it is less than 3.2mm height and it recesses 1.6mm into the 1.6mm PCB.

Comment: Why don't you just manufacture your own FPC with USB connector on it?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a small exterior data I/O connector. All such connectors are designed for a particular port (e.g., HDMI). There are no small general purpose exterior data I/O connectors. There are general-purpose interior connectors, but those are not suitable for use by the end user. There are general-purpose exterior connectors, but they are relatively large. So, I am afraid that you'll need a custom connector: beaucoup time and money. Better yet, reconsider the mechanical design to allow a standard USB-C connector.